# How much does it cost to create a token on Solana?

Tags: nft, token

What is the current cost to create my own custom token on Solana with a supply of 1 or 1 billion? If I create a token which is a supply of just 1 (NFT) is it the same cost? Or do NFT's operate in a different way and cost?

Answer (score 1):

Whether a supply of one or one billion, the cost is the same.

The standard way to create new tokens or NFTs on Solana is with the SPL Token Program. https://spl.solana.com/token

Each custom token or NFT on the SPL Token program is represented by a Mint account, which stores metadata about the token, including the total supply, the number of decimal places, who is the mint authority, etc. This is why the cost is the same regardless of your token's supply -- the mint supply is just a `u64` stored on a metadata account.

I plucked a random Mint account off main-net and looking at its balance, looks like it currently costs 0.0014616 SOL for a rent-exempt balance.

Of course, in order to store a custom token, a signer would need to have a Token Account to store metadata like their balance, etc. Those currently look like they cost 0.00203928 SOL to create with a rent-exempt balance (again sourced by plucking a random SPL token account off a block explorer).

These token accounts are set up once, and can be closed and their lamports redeemed (but the token account's "custom token" balance must be zero). As a convenience to any token's recipient, these token accounts can be created and paid for by the sender. For more information on that, see the "associated token account" section in the docs I linked to above.

Comment: how do airdrops works then? I get so much spam in my wallets. If an org is sending out tokens to 10,000 wallets with new token, wouldn't that be 0.00203928 X 10000 = 20.3928 SOL? at current prices is worth $2000 right? Just double checking if my logic is accurate.

100,000 people would be roughly $20K. 1M people is $200K.

sending a stimulus check system like America did during covid would have been around 476 million payments, which on solana would be 970697 SOL, around $97M, if the stimulus was a new token right?

Seems quite expensive....